# the app doesn't get rtl when using rtl locale in vuetify v.3

Tags: vuejs3, multilingual, vuetifyjs3

I'm using **vuetify v.3** that is recently released

I have problem to use `rtl` support in Vuetify 3

as it said [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#rtl)

> RTL (Right To Left) support is built in for all localizations that
> ship with Vuetify. If a supported language is flagged as RTL, all
> content directions are automatically switched

this is **plugins/vuetify.ts**

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { fa } from 'vuetify/locale'
export default createVuetify({
  locale: {
    locale: 'fa',
    fallback: 'fa',
    messages: { fa },
  },
})
```

As you see I've imported `fa` ( farsi ,persian ) from locale and it is a `rtl` locale **But** the **app** **doesn't** get rtl .

and as it said [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#rtl) , `fa` is supported locale

> Supported languages Currently Vuetify provides translations in the
> following languages:
>
> af - Afrikaans (Afrikaans) ar - Arabic (اللغة العربية) az -
> Azerbaijani (Azərbaycan) bg - Bulgarian (български) ca - Catalan
> (català) ckb - Central Kurdish (کوردی) cs - Czech (čeština) da -
> Danish (Dansk) de - German (Deutsch) el - Greek (Ελληνικά) en -
> English es - Spanish (Español) et - Estonian (eesti) fa - Persian
> (فارسی) fi - Finnish (suomi)

Also when inspect page I see that `lang` attribute for html tag is set to `en`

[image]
I think maybe maybe there is something wrong with my codes.

what is the **problem** and **How** can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the RTL property as [shown](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#creating-a-custom-locale) for custom locales (even though yours is built-in) ?

Comment: Yes I did , nothing happened !

Comment: Could be a bug in Vuetify. It's not the only bug in v3 of Vuetify despite their claims that it is out of the beta status. From my experience it's not yet production ready (as opposed to v2).

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

you should add rtl property to locale object and ***set your rtl locale as true.***

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { fa } from 'vuetify/locale'
export default createVuetify({
  locale: {
    locale: 'fa',
    fallback: 'fa',
    messages: { fa },
    rtl: {fa: true},
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using I18N ?
if so than make sure to
legacy: false,

to the call to createI18n({...}).

for me not having it made vuetify ignore rtl for all my locales.